# Need help reformatting a table

Tags: tables

I don't use LaTeX that often, and I'm currently trying to reformat a paper that I originally wrote over a year ago.  The new format specification has tighter margins than the the old, so I have this

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\scriptsize
\centering
\caption{Performance Summary}
\label{PerfSummary}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{1-4} \cline{6-9}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Method} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Average} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Method} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Maximum} \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
Triage++ & Reactive & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.21 &  & Triage++ & Schedule & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.94 \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
Triage++ & Schedule & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.05 &  & Triage++ & Fixed $\alpha_{++}$ &  & 10.7 \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
Triage++ & Fixed $\alpha_{++}$ &  & 9.81 &  & Triage++ & Reactive & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.68 \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
Triage++ & Schedule & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low & 9.46 &  & Triage++ & Schedule & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low & 10.49 \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
Triage+ & Reactive & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low & 9.35 &  & Triage+ & Fixed $\alpha_{+}$ &  & 10.11 \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
Triage++ & Reactive & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low & 8.27 &  & Triage+ & Reactive & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low & 9.92 \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
Triage+ & Schedule & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low & 6.23 &  & Triage+ & Schedule & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low & 9.83 \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
Triage+ & Schedule & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High & 5.56 &  & Triage+ & Schedule & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High & 9.74 \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
Triage+ & Fixed $\alpha_{+}$ &  & 4.6 &  & Triage++ & Reactive & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low & 9.14 \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
Triage+ & Reactive & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High & 1.3 &  & Triage+ & Reactive & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High & 2.38 \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{6-9} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Which produces this table

[image]

Which you can see is now too wide.  I'd like to "stack" the two portions within a single table but am not sure how to go about that.  Alternatively I could separate them into two tables with distinct numbers...I can handle that.

So I guess I'm asking for a) aesthetic advice, do you think they read better as unique tables or "stacked" and b) how to stack them, if necessary....

Comment: I would recommend: 1. Create two tables, one on top of the other (two `tabulars` in a single `table` environment). 2. Use the `booktabs` package and eliminate all the horizontal and vertical lines, except the one under the title line.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter suggested, the tables look better when you remove the rules. Using booktabs, the table(s) will turn out better looking :-)

I have used the data you have given and made it into two tabulars withing a single table.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\scriptsize
\centering
\caption{Performance Summary}
\label{PerfSummary}
\begin{tabular}{lllS}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Method} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Average}          \\
\midrule
  Triage++ & Reactive            & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.21 \\
  Triage++ & Schedule            & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.05 \\
  Triage++ & Fixed $\alpha_{++}$ &                           & 9.81  \\
  Triage++ & Schedule            & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low  & 9.46  \\
  Triage+  & Reactive            & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low   & 9.35  \\
  Triage++ & Reactive            & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low  & 8.27  \\
  Triage+  & Schedule            & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low   & 6.23  \\
  Triage+  & Schedule            & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High  & 5.56  \\
  Triage+  & Fixed $\alpha_{+}$  &                           & 4.6   \\
  Triage+  & Reactive            & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High  & 1.3   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{lllS}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Method} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Maximum}          \\
\midrule
  Triage++ & Schedule            & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.94 \\
  Triage++ & Fixed $\alpha_{++}$ &                           & 10.7 \\ 
  Triage++ & Reactive            & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.68 \\
  Triage++ & Schedule            & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low  & 10.49 \\
  Triage+  & Fixed $\alpha_{+}$  &                           & 10.11 \\
  Triage+  & Reactive            & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low   & 9.92 \\ 
  Triage+  & Schedule            & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low   & 9.83 \\ 
  Triage+  & Schedule            & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High  & 9.74 \\ 
  Triage++ & Reactive            & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low  & 9.14 \\ 
  Triage+  & Reactive            & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High  & 2.38 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output is as shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your two tables can fit on a single horizontal block if you use `geometry, which defines more sensible margins if you don't have marginal notes. You even can use footnote size. I use the`S` columntype for the numeracil column
s, to have  an alignment on the decimal dot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, caption, booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \footnotesize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}\captionsetup{font =footnotesize}
  \centering\sisetup{table-format =2.2, table-number-alignment=center}
  \caption{Performance Summary}
  \label{PerfSummary}
  \begin{tabular}{lllSclllS}
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-4} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{6-9}
    \cmidrule(lr){1-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}\cmidrule(lr){9-9}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Method} &{Average} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Method} & {Maximum} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-3} \cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}\cmidrule{9-9}
    Triage++ & Reactive & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.21 & & Triage++ & Schedule & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.94 \\
    Triage++ & Schedule & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.05 & & Triage++ & Fixed $\alpha_{++}$ & & 10.7 \\
    Triage++ & Fixed $\alpha_{++}$ & & 9.81 & & Triage++ & Reactive & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins High & 10.68 \\
    Triage++ & Schedule & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low & 9.46 & & Triage++ & Schedule & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low & 10.49 \\
    Triage+ & Reactive & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low & 9.35 & & Triage+ & Fixed $\alpha_{+}$ & & 10.11 \\
    Triage++ & Reactive & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low & 8.27 & & Triage+ & Reactive & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low & 9.92 \\
    Triage+ & Schedule & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low & 6.23 & & Triage+ & Schedule & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins Low & 9.83 \\
    Triage+ & Schedule & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High & 5.56 & & Triage+ & Schedule & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High & 9.74 \\
    Triage+ & Fixed $\alpha_{+}$ & & 4.6 & & Triage++ & Reactive & $\alpha_{++}$ Begins Low & 9.14 \\
    Triage+ & Reactive & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High & 1.3 & & Triage+ & Reactive & $\alpha_{+}$ Begins High & 2.38 \\
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-4} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{6-9}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]